# Google Maps - prefer 'pleasant' route over fastest

Tags: google-maps-navigation, maps

Is there a way of telling the Google Maps route finder that I would prefer the least number of junctions / traffic lights, or if traffic is heavy in areas, the route with least time spent 'sitting'.

A route that is 1 min faster than another, yet involves more stop/start driving can be more frustrating than one which is flowing.

Generally, when routes are within ~3 mins difference of one another, I'm not bothered about the quickest, I just want the least irritating one.

Comment: See [Leslie post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/maps/qKnJRTCE0wQ) Which implies that *navigation* and *real time data* both need to be available and that condition is limited to certain regions only